# In SQL, how can I count the result of a UNION?

Tags: sql, count, union

Suppose I have a query such as

```
SELECT * from frequency where (...) 
UNION 
SELECT * from frequency where  (...)
```

How can I count how many results are returned from the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` function with subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Row_Counts
FROM 
(
  SELECT * from frequency where (...) 
  UNION 
  SELECT * from frequency where  (...)
) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `UNION`? If you combine the `WHERE` clauses, you could get count this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM frequency 
WHERE (...) OR (...)
```

Comment: Yes, much simpler, though it should be noted that this will only work with UNION and not UNION ALL...